# Android Studio で仮想デバイスが実行できません

Tags: android-studio

Android Studioでのアプリ開発を勉強しているのですが、いまだにHello Worldの実行ができません。
仮想デバイスで表示させたいのですが仮想デバイスが動かない状態です。

また、実行の緑色の三角形ボタンを押しても、時間切れというような警告が出たりして実行できません。

Comment: PCの、CPUの種類はなんですか？CPUの種類毎に調整が必要な場合があったと思います。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。後ほど確認してすぐに返信します。

Comment: CPUの種類ですが、Core i3-8145Uです。

Comment: インテル系ですね。私の回答の２番目のリンクにある設定がまだの場合、設定すると解決するかもしれません。vt-xには対応していると思います。

Comment: リンク等貼ってくださりありがとうございます。バーチャルデバイスの画面が小さいものや性能の低いものを作成してみると良いんですね。AndroidStudioを入れて動かすことはできてますがやはりパソコンの性能に対して少しキャパオーバーになってるようで、パソコンの動きは悪いです…。少し性能低めのデバイスを作ってみます。

Answer (score 0):

この辺りの情報は参照されましたか？
もしまだのものがありましたら、一度確認されることをお勧めします。

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-troubleshooting?hl=ja
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration?hl=ja
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator?hl=ja

私がこれまで遭遇した中での重くなる原因は、概ねハードウェア アクセラレーションの設定が適切でないパターンで、これは非常に動作が重たくなって止まったりタイムアウトしたりします。
あとはエミュレータとして作成したデバイスの性能がPCの性能に対して高すぎる場合も問題が出ます。
その場合は画面サイズが小さい、性能の低いデバイスを作成すると動かせる場合がありますので試してみてください。PCのメモリ不足も重くなって止まる場合があります。

Comment: リンク等貼ってくださりありがとうございます。バーチャルデバイスの画面が小さいものや性能の低いものを作成してみると良いんですね。AndroidStudioを入れて動かすことはできてますがやはりパソコンの性能に対して少しキャパオーバーになってるようで、パソコンの動きは悪いです…。少し性能低めのデバイスを作ってみます。　また、2つ目のリンク先を見たのですが、このリンクに載っている設定は全て行ったほうが良いでしょうか。当方素人のため色々お聞きしてすみません。

Comment: ２つ目のリンクのうち、Intel Virtualization Technology（VT-x）を使ってみてください。CPUが対応していると思います。適用するとかなり高速になるので、タイムアウトなどしにくくなります。

Comment: VT-Xが有効かを確認したところ有効でした。また、性能の低めなバーチャルデバイスを作成して実行してみました。画面は起動画面からホーム画面へと動いたりして進歩はありましたが、アプリの実行をしようとしたところINSTALLED_FAILED_OLDER_SDKというエラーが出てしまいました。重ね重ねすみません。

Comment: Androidのプロジェクト設定の方で、設定されているAPIのバージョンがインストールしようとした端末と互換性が無いのだと思うので変えてみてください。多分SDKのバージョン設定(min sdk version)が合致していません。

Comment: または、作られた端末のSDKが古いものになっている可能性もあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。min SDK version を確認したいと思います。